# Expectation of an event

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expectation of an event](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47520/expectation-of-an-event)

Let $A$ be an array of length 1000 with all entries 0. I want to fill up $A$ with ones using the following approach:

Each time I take three random integers $(j_1,j_2,j_3)$ from [1,1000] with replacement such that

1. Set $A[j_1]=1;$
2. If $A[j_2]=1$ and $A[j_3]=0$, then set $A[j_3]=1$ or, if $A[j_2]=0$ and $A[j_3]=1$, then set $A[j_2]=1$.

What is the expected number of such trials to fill up A with all ones?

If $A[j_2]=A[j_3]=0$, just continue. With replacement means $j_2$ may be equal to $j_3$ or any previous $j_2$ etc.

Comment: This is easy to solve (exactly) with dynamic programming, but I'm not sure how to do it analytically.

Comment: I'm assuming if $j_2, j_3$ are both zero you just continue?

Comment: What means that you are taking random variables from [1,1000] *with replacement*?

Comment: @Gortaur: it means that you $j_1$ could equal $j_2$, etc.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is 2055.23...  Looking forward to seeing if anyone can do this analytically.

Comment: @Neil - could you please clarify how did you obtain it? Since the time horizon of the problem is infinite, for me it's not clear how to apply DP. I also thought about finite state ($2^{1000}$) MC but if we can calculate there an average time of reaching a single state?

Comment: @Gortaur: There are only 1001 states.  See the linked answer.  Looks like I made a mistake in my code; the answer is 2861...